# How to disable function in one section of Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, hook, woocommerce

I'm using a product add ons plugin for Woocommerce which is great - allows lots of custom options for a product (engraving etc). This displays on the main product page fine and works well.

In the shop pages though and any other section like related products these options show too, which ruin the look of those sections.

I'm waiting for a response from the plugin developer but just wondered if anyone here could point me in at least the general direction of where I should look to solve this - been on it for days now. I'm new to removing actions etc.

Thanks (I know there's not enough info here but a suggestion would be great)

Dave

Comment: Did you try not displaying these options using css ?

Comment: Endlessly! Good suggestion though, thanks. I can hide with CSS but it hides from the main product page too. If I could somehow say" if this shows up anywhere but on the main product display then display:none. I just can't find a way to use the 'featured products' sections as an 'if' statement - if that makes anysense...